# open home page app not open

Tags: java, jsp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTMr6.png)

this i mage show folders.

next servlet code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
//import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet(name = "HomeServlet", urlPatterns = {"/home"})
public class HomeServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public HomeServlet() {
        super();
    }


    /*protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Forward to /WEB-INF/views/homeView.jsp
        // (Users can not access directly into JSP pages placed in WEB-INF)
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/Career/WebContent/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
      //  dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }*/


     @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}


}
```

next index jsp page:

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${contextPath}/css/styles.css"
    type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="header" id="header"></div>

        <div class="navbar">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="/index.jsp">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="job_offer.html" target="_blank">Offer a job</a></li>
            </ul>

            <a href="index.html" target="_blank"><img
                src="${contextPath}/images/meterbrain.gif"
                style="float: right; width: 12%;" /></a>
        </div>

        <div class="content">

            <div class="rightblock">
                <div class="headmenu">Prolog System</div>
                <div class="bodymenu">
                    <a href="#"><img src="${contextPath}/images/meterbrain.gif" /></a>
                </div>


            </div>

            <div class="leftblock">
                <div class="headmenu">Advertisements</div>
                <div class="bodymenu" id="advertise1">
                    <a href="#"><img src="${contextPath}/images/advertisement.jpg" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="bodymenu" id="advertise1">
                    <a href="#"><img src="${contextPath}/images/advertisement.jpg" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="bodymenu" id="advertise1">
                    <a href="#"><img src="${contextPath}/images/advertisement.jpg" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

next web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Career</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**and another problem**
 if i run this page why i can't import css and image to jsp and where add these files in eclipse folders.

last update of image project folders:

[image]

Still can't import css and images in jsp file.
and same problem with request another jsp page.
Any help.

Comment: move out your index.jsp from web-inf and put it directly in webContent

Comment: why it's not work only if i add jsp in webContent ?                                          And if want add more jsp file what i have to do ? and in which folder i add css and image files?

Comment: it's all in the webContent , you can create a folder call it css and another one images and another one call it myJsp and on it you can edit your owen pages and stylesheet , see the answer under it may help you

Comment: did you copy those images and css files directly to your project or you created them in your project in running time ?

Comment: i copied them in my project but not in running time.

Comment: you made it wrong try to copy them in eclipse running like you cope a simple file and then go to your webContent in eclipse and paste it !! so do not paste it in the folder directly !! with this method it will be deployed in the server

Comment: i used this  href="<c:url value="/css/styles.css"/>" jSTL tag and <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>  used this for images href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/MyJsps/login.jsp". Now it's running.  thanks for help .

Comment: Glad you made it work :)

Comment: thanks :). u know some  websites have open sorce project for javaee ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the relative path starting from the WAR file to getRequestDispatcher() method.

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

From the screenshot, I cannot see where you have kept your css and image files. Create folders 'css' and 'images' under WebContent. Include them like this in your JSP.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${contextPath}/css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
<img src="${contextPath}/images/meterbrain.gif" />
```

Comment: i made change like u wrote but still can't appear css and image in the page

Comment: post the updated screenshot of your project folders.